# if i create an android application which is using custom service written by me , will it works same with the built in service

Tags: android, service, android-source, intentservice, android-intentservice

CUSTOM SERVICE IN ANDROID

Let's say I develop an application which is using Bluetooth Manager Service which is in AOSP. But if I add a new hardware and create a HAL, AIDL, JNI, Framework Service for that hardware, will it works the same way if try to access that service or will there be any changes.

I was creating an application which uses service written by me.
But i want to know how to access that service in by application code.
How to add that service in AOSP

Answer (score 0):

You can create a system service in the OS, create it's manager and then access it in the application layer via a custom jar which contains the manager class.
Refer to this article, highly recommend to read this, explains pretty much everything required:
https://medium.com/android-news/system-service-in-aosp-750007d39555